# How many ECMO machines does China have?

Tags: virus, lungs, mechanical-ventilation

Is there any data on how many ECMO machines in China? I know that there are about 260 machines in the united states but I have found no data about China on such matter. I want to compare the preparedness of the USA for coronavirus compared to China.

Comment: 260 seems like a pittance. Any word on if more will be aquired?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21252/is-there-any-identified-policy-china-is-doing-to-succesfully-reduce-coronavirus/21259#21259

Comment: WHO said 5 ecmo per hospital in Wuhan

Answer (score 1):

*China has sent 67 ECMO machines to Hubei, said Luo Junjie, an official from the Ministry of Industry and Information Technology, adding that the ministry will import more ECMO machines for Hubei and Wuhan, the capital city of the province.Mar 4, 2020*

http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2020-03/04/c_138843056.htm

this doesn't tell how many ECMO machines actually are available in China. But I'd rather ask how reasonable your neighbors are and respect the behaving orders to stop the spreading of the virus instead of comparing and counting the numbers of ECMO machines.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31269589

Comment: Upvoting because you sort of answered the question. Truth be told China doesn't publish all her medial and military resources. I'm impressed you found out what you did however with so many 10's of thousands infected it is no wonder the daily death count from China is so high. It makes me wonder how many ECMO machines are in my city should I need the services of one and am at the end of the line.